# Несколько уникальных значений

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

Есть таблица в которой связаны идентификаторы пользователей с идентификаторами задачи.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    ID int NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
    TaskID INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (TaskID) REFERENCES task(ID),
    UserID INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES users(ID),
);
```

Пользователю можно внести запись с идентификатором задачи только один раз.
Т.е одному пользователю можно присвоить любое количество задач но они не должны повторяться.
К одной задаче может иметь доступ любое количество пользователей.

Как это можно реализовать средствами БД?

Comment: Создать уникальный композитный индекс. `ALTER TABLE test CREATE UNIQUE (TaskID, UserID);`.

Comment: потенциально тут id не нужен. просто пару user-task сделать первичным ключом. А если оставлять уникальным индексом, тогда id сделать ключом,  а не индексом. В противном случае mysql вам создаст неявный первичный ключ и будете тратить место. Каскадные связи еще проставьте для обеспечения целостности данных.

Answer (score 0):

Cоздайте триггер:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER test_prevent_duplicates
BEFORE INSERT ON test
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE duplicate INT;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO duplicate
    FROM test
    WHERE TaskID = NEW.TaskID AND UserID = NEW.UserID;
    IF duplicate > 0 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Повторяющаяся запись для TaskID и UserID';
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Ещё способ - использовать хранимую процедуру:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE add_test_record(IN task_id INT, IN user_id INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE duplicate INT;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO duplicate
    FROM test
    WHERE TaskID = task_id AND UserID = user_id;
    IF duplicate > 0 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Duplicate entry for TaskID and UserID';
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO test (TaskID, UserID) VALUES (task_id, user_id);
    END IF;
END;
```

Ещё могу предложить создать уникальный констрейнт на комбинацию TaskID и UserID в таблице test, чтобы исключить дубликаты записей с одним и тем же таском и айди:

```
ALTER TABLE test
ADD CONSTRAINT unique_task_user UNIQUE(TaskID, UserID);
```

при появлении дубликата выбросится ошибка.

Comment: Конечно же, самый нормальный вариант надо написать последним?